# Magento : How to get qty of a specific product in an order item?

Tags: php, magento, foreach

I have this script to help me get the QTY of a specific product from an order item in Magento 1.6. This should be visualized in a simple table. This is my code so far:

```
// Load the product collection
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $id = $product->getId();
    $product_name = $product->getName();

    $order_output = '';
    $order_output .= '<table style="width: 500px">';
        $order_output .= '<tr><td colspan="3"><strong>'.$product_name.'</strong></td></tr>';
        $order_output .= '<tr><td><strong>Order id</strong></td><td><strong>Total price</strong></td><td><strong>Qty</strong></td><td><strong>Customer name</strong></td></tr>';

        // Get all unique order IDs for items with specifix product ID
        $time = time();
        $to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
        $from = date('2012-07-01 08:00:00');
        $orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $id)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
        ->load();

        foreach ($orderItems as $order) {
             $order_data = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order['order_id']);
             $items = $order_data->getColletion();
             $order_id = $order['order_id'];
             $total = $order_data->getGrandTotal();
             $customer_name = $order_data->getCustomerName();

             foreach ($items as $item) {
                $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                if ($product_id == $id) {
                    $number_of_prod =  $item->getQtyOrdered();
                }       
             }

             $order_output .= '</tr>';
                $order_output .= '<td width="20%" align="left">'.$order_id.'</td>';
                $order_output .= '<td width="20%">'.number_format($total, 2, '.', '').' RMB</td>';
                $order_output .= '<td width="20%">'.$number_of_prod.'</td>';
                $order_output .= '<td width="40%">'.$customer_name.'</td>';
             $order_output .= '</tr>';     
        }
    $order_output .= '</table>';

    header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    echo $order_output;
}
```

Everything is populating correctly and the only thing missing is the QTY. You can see the attached image for the output.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I use:

```
$items = $order_data->getAllItems();
```

I get the Qty but now all the orders of respective products is not listed.

Comment: Also when I echo $product_id that var is empty so I guess that this line: $product_id = $item->getProductId(); is wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried the alternate methods to get the qty ordered?

```
$item->getData('qty_ordered');
```

or

```
$item['qty_ordered'];
```

Comment: @JoshuaSchuler Can i get MYSQL query?

Answer (score 15):

There is another simple function for this :

```
$item->getQtyOrdered();
```